# Different model resource_fields for different blueprints

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful

I have a Flask-RESTful based API, which currently has two blueprints, allowing me to version the API with backwards-incompatible changes.

```
from api_1_0 import api_bp as api_1_0_blueprint
app.register_blueprint(api_1_0_blueprint, url_prefix='/api/v1.0')

from api_1_1 import api_bp as api_1_1_blueprint
app.register_blueprint(api_1_1_blueprint, url_prefix='/api/v1.1')
```

Whenever I need to make a backwards incompatible change (e.g. removing an endpoint), I create a new blueprint. Currently, the blueprints all share the same `models.py` file, defining the database tables and the JSON representation of each model.

I now have a need to create a new version of the API where a particular resource field `email` will be changed from a `string` data type to `array[string]`. The existing versions of the API must retain the original resource representation.

I have tried placing a `models.py` file in each blueprint folder so that the newer blueprint `v1.2` can have it's own `resource_fields` definition, but in doing so I end up with this error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Table '' is already defined for this MetaData instance. Specify 'extend_existing=True' to
>   redefine options and columns on an existing Table object.

I understand this is happening because I'm essentially defining the same database tables for every blueprint. Really all I want is to change the `resource_fields` per blueprint, as the database schema is always going to be the same across all API versions, it is just the JSON response which might change. (I will use the `@property` decorator to create the new fields)

Given this setup, how can I change the `resource_fields` per blueprint?

Below is some sample (simplified) code from my project.

**app/models.py** - https://gist.github.com/MattHealy/4c9d2c03615e3381774235bbbc398437

```
from app import db
from flask.ext.restful import fields

@swagger.model
class Contact(db.Model):

      resource_fields = {
        'email': fields.String
      }

      email = db.Column(db.String(100))
```

**app/api_1_1/resources/contacts.py** - https://gist.github.com/MattHealy/556c93fe33a929e469ae18bf76db83b1

```
from flask.ext.restful import Resource, marshal, reqparse
from ... models import Contact

class ContactAPI(Resource):

    "Retrieve details of a single contact"
    @swagger.operation(
        nickname = "contact",
        responseClass=Contact.__name__,
        parameters=[
            {
              "name": "id",
              "description": "ID of the contact",
              "required": True,
              "allowMultiple": False,
              "dataType": "int",
              "paramType": "path"
            },
        ],
        responseMessages=[
            {
              "code": 200,
              "message": "Contact retrieved"
            },
          ],
        summary="Get details of a single contact",
        )
    def get(self, id):
        contact = Contact.query.get(id)
        return { 'contact': marshal(contact, Contact.resource_fields) }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a different (locally generated) resource_fields dict per blueprint. In your specific case, you could use resource_fields as an attribute of the `ContactAPI` class and pass it to the marshalling function.

In the specific case you show above (change of type for the email field) I think you will also need to build a custom Fields class (based on fields.Raw) to accommodate the type of output you might want to get.